# R: Apply function to calculate mean of a single column of dataframe across a list

Tags: r, list, apply, lapply

Some sample data

I have three lists

```
    loc <- c("A","A","A","B","B","B")
    sub.loc <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3)

    set.seed(123)

    df1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(loc,sub.loc, round(rnorm(6),digits =2)))
    df2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(loc,sub.loc, round(rnorm(6),digits =2)))
    df3 <- as.data.frame(cbind(loc,sub.loc, round(rnorm(6),digits =2)))

    list.name <- list(df1,df2,df3)
```

I want to produce a single file that has mean and sd of the third column `V3`.

```
Something like: 

    loc    sub.loc        V3                                      v4
    A        1        mean(c(-0.56,0.46,0.4))      sd(c(-0.56,0.46,0.4)) 
    A        2        mean(c(-0.23,-1.27,0.11))    sd(c(-0.23,-1.27,0.11))
    A        3        mean(c(-0.56,-0.69, 1.56))   sd(c(-0.56,-0.69, 1.56))
    B        1       mean(c(0.07,-0.45,1.79))      sd(c(0.07,-0.45,1.79))
    B        2        mean(c(0.13,1.22,0.5))       sd(c(0.13,1.22,0.5))
    B        3        mean(c(1.72,0.36,-1.97))     sd(c(1.72,0.36,-1.97))
```

My actual data in column `V3`` has NAs

I thought of using lapply

```
    lapply(list.name, function(x) mean(x, na.rm = T))

    lapply(list.name, function(x) sd(x, na.rm = T))
```

But both of them give me NAs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `dplyr`. First, I'm not sure how accurate your sample data above matches your real data but right now all your "numeric" values are factors. You really shouldn't use `cbind()` inside `as.data.frame()`, you can leave it out.

But with your example data above, we can stack the data into one larger data.frame and then do a simple group_by to get the values you want

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(list.name, .id="from") %>% 
  mutate(V3=as.numeric(as.character(V3))) %>%  # fix the factors from the sample
  group_by(loc, sub.loc) %>% 
  summarize(mean=mean(V3, na.rm=T), sd=sd(V3, na.rm=T))
```

Comment: The `.id="from"` tells `bind_rows()` to add a new column so we know from which element of the list the value same from. I realize now that we probably don't actually need that there at all. Just force of habbit for me I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are running `mean()` and `sd()` across entire dataframe which contains non-numeric columns and hence `NA`.

Consider base R's `by` (object-oriented wrapper of `tapply`) where you first stack list of dataframes with `rbind` and then run aggregations across *loc* and *sub.loc* groupings:

```
stackdf <- do.call(rbind, list.name)
stackdf
#    loc sub.loc    V3
# 1    A       1 -0.56
# 2    A       2 -0.23
# 3    A       3  1.56
# 4    B       1  0.07
# 5    B       2  0.13
# 6    B       3  1.72
# 7    A       1  0.46
# 8    A       2 -1.27
# 9    A       3 -0.69
# 10   B       1 -0.45
# 11   B       2  1.22
# 12   B       3  0.36
# 13   A       1  0.40
# 14   A       2  0.11
# 15   A       3 -0.56
# 16   B       1  1.79
# 17   B       2  0.50
# 18   B       3 -1.97

dfs <- by(stackdf, stackdf[c("loc", "sub.loc")], FUN=function(df) {      
  data.frame(loc = df$loc[1],
             sub.loc = df$sub.loc[1],
             mean = mean(df$V3, na.rm=TRUE),
             sd = sd(df$V3, na.rm=TRUE))
})

finaldf <- do.call(rbind, dfs)
finaldf
#   loc sub.loc        mean        sd
# 1   A       1  0.10000000 0.5723635
# 2   B       1  0.47000000 1.1723481
# 3   A       2 -0.46333333 0.7189808
# 4   B       2  0.61666667 0.5542863
# 5   A       3  0.10333333 1.2631838
# 6   B       3  0.03666667 1.8661279
```